# how to free resources in generic class implementing IEnumerable<T> when iteration is interrupted?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I have following class that wraps static methods of class MyDatabase and I need to close _cursor even if iteration is interrupted.

```
public class DbWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : struct
{
    public static Dictionary<Type, int> _tablenumber = new Dictionary<Type, int>()
        {
           {  typeof(MyStruct), 100 }
           {  typeof(SomeStruct), 200 }
        };

    Cursor _cursor;

    public DbWrapper()
    {
        _cursor = MyDatabase.OpenCursorAll(_tablenumber[typeof(T)]);
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        T row;
        while (MyDatabase.Fetch<T>(_cursor, out row))
        {
            yield return row;
        }
        MyDatabase.CloseCursor(_cursor);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        var me = this as IEnumerable<T>;
        return me.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I could do this by making class implement IDisposable and creating DbWrapper instance in using block before the iteration. However I would like to minimize the calling code. I'm also wondering is it good style to call constructor directly in foreach:

```
        foreach (var eRow in new DbWrapper<MyStruct>())
        {
            myList.Add(eRow.Name);
        }
```

or should I have static method that returns the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to minimize the calling code

If `Cursor` implements `IDisposable` you can just get rid of the creating of the cursor in the constructor and wrap the `yield` statement in a `using` block:

```
IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    using(_cursor = MyDatabase.OpenCursorAll(_tablenumber[typeof(T)]))
    {
        T row;
        while (MyDatabase.Fetch<T>(_cursor, out row))
        {
            yield return row;
        }
        MyDatabase.CloseCursor(_cursor);
    }
}
```

Note that `Dispose` is automatically called when using a `foreach` even if the enumerator is not fully enumerated.